# unable to access variable value in foreach php

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')->select('categoryid')->get();
    foreach ($categories as $category) 
      {
         $categoryid = $category->categoryid;
         die($categoryid);//i am getting blank result here
      }
```

After `var_dump($category->categoryid);`
I am getting `int(5)`

Why am I not getting a value in `categoryid` as `5`?

Comment: If you want to show just id then you can try to `echo $categoryid;`.Hope this will be worked. Read manual for var_dump http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php .

Comment: i want the value of  categoryid into $categoryid because i want to use it later

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [manual of php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), you will find var_dump will show both the **type** and **value**.

```
void var_dump ( mixed $expression [, mixed $... ] )
```

This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its **type** and **value**. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

It is normal to get `int(5)`, which means the type of `$category->categoryid` is `int` and the value of `$category->categoryid` is `5`.

Comment: i want to pass categoryid to another function thats why i need the value of $categoryid.. after executing my code i am getting  blnk results at after die

Comment: Maybe you can try $categoryid = (int)$category->categoryid;

Answer (score 0):

`die()` is just a reference of `exit()`. That is, both die and exit do the exact same thing.

[According to the manual for exit():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

Because you are outputting an integer, it will not display the number 5. Instead, you should probably do something like:

```
die((string)$categoryid);
```

By casting it to a string, you are forcing the `die` construct to output the value as a string, rather than return it as a status code.

Another option would be to `echo` the category id and then exit:

```
echo $categoryid;
exit
```

Comment: its not about die ? i want to use $categoryid value somewhere else. its resulting blank . when i die i dont get any result not even int(5)

Comment: You don't get any result, because `die()` isn't outputting anything. And if you have `die()`, no code after it will be run either. Change `die($categoryid);` to `die((string)$categoryid);` and it should output the value.